# does EI 7.0.1 contain BPS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-business-process, wso2-esb

Does EI 7.0.1 contain Business-process server? Cause in MI, Ballerina, SI directories no business-process directory. Where is BPS? I want to configure workflows for API-M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BPS is not included in EI 7 series and you might have to use EI 6x series if you need it.